# Exibir array dentro do chartjs

Tags: php, array, chartjs

Será que poderiam me ajudar com a seguinte situação:

Possuo uma coluna chamada **tipo_evento** , nela após o preenchimento de um formulário será inserida algum dos 4 itens: Colisão, PT, FURTO, Roubo.

Estou querendo fazer uma consulta e saber quantas vezes cada um dos itens aparece na coluna e exibi-los em gráfico usando chartjs.

Segue código abaixo:

```
    public function contar2()
    {
        try {
            $query = $this->bd->prepare("SELECT tipo_evento, COUNT(tipo_evento) AS Quantidade FROM vistorias GROUP BY tipo_evento HAVING COUNT(tipo_evento) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(tipo_evento) DESC");
            $contar_dados = array($_GET['tipo_evento']);
            $query->execute(array($contar_dados));
            $conta = $query->rowCount();

            if ($conta > 0) {
                $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

Na página onde quero exibir os itens, estou chamando a função da seguinte forma:

```
   $contar2 = $acoes->contar2();
   $furto = $contar2[2]['tipo_evento'];
   $furto2 = $contar[2]['Quantidade'];
```

Coloquei o comando abaixo na página e me retornou o array da seguinte forma:

```
    echo '<pre>';
print_r($cliente);
echo '</pre>';
```

```
[
{
0: {
0: "Colisão",
1: "4",
tipo_evento: "Colisão",
Quantidade: "4"
},
1: {
0: "PT",
1: "3",
tipo_evento: "PT",
Quantidade: "3"
},
2: {
0: "Furto",
1: "3",
tipo_evento: "Furto",
Quantidade: "3"
},
3: {
0: "Opcionais",
1: "2",
tipo_evento: "Opcionais",
Quantidade: "2"
}
},
"</pre>",
```

Teria como pegar essas informações do array e inserir no gráfico chartjs ?

Eu até consigo pegar elas se eu fizer:

```
$furto = $contar2[2]['Quantidade'];
echo "Meu Array possui: ".$furto2.' elementos';
```

Dessa forma, ele me retorna quantas vezes foi exibido, porém não consigo colocar dentro do chartjs...

Obrigado desde já !

Comment: Opa, acho que o jeito mais facil é transformar isso em json e passar pro teu frontend msm, seja usando requisições ajax ou criando objeto javascript com o php na hora de exibir a sua pagina tipo `<script> var obj = <?php echo json_encode($seu_array) ?> </script>`

Comment: @andre_luiss - É, me desculpe a ignorância, mas não entendi como eu poderia chamar os valores dentro do gráfico, poderia exemplificar um pouco mais por gentileza

Comment: Por ser chartJS vc tem q mandar um array pra ele, mas cabe a vc formatar esse array pra se encaixar no grafico e fazer sentido. Se voce tiver `$array = ['fruta' => 'banana']`, usando `json_encode` o output do array seria uma string `{"fruta":"banana"}`, sendo assim vc ja é capaz de manipular via javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de algumas tentativas, consegui resolver meu problema da seguinte forma, vou postar aqui caso ajude alguém futuramente.

Criei um arquivo com o nome app.js com o seguinte código:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chart.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            var nomearray = [];
            var vendasarray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                nomearray.push(data[i].tipo_evento);
                vendasarray.push(data[i].Quantidade);

            }
            grafico(nomearray, vendasarray);
        }

    });
})

function grafico(nome, vendas) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'doughnut',
        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: nome,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: ['#f56954', '#00a65a', '#f39c12', '#00c0ef', '#3c8dbc', '#d2d6de'],
                data: vendas
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });

}
```

Em seguida, criei um arquivo chamado chart.php para enviar os dados, com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NOMEDATABELA;port=3306;charset=utf8', 'usuario', 'senha');

$sql = "SELECT tipo_evento, COUNT(tipo_evento) AS Quantidade FROM vistorias GROUP BY tipo_evento HAVING COUNT(tipo_evento) > 1 ORDER BY COUNT(tipo_evento) DESC";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute();


while($results = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $result[] = $results;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```